# Extract the decade from a year

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----+
|             core_id|                guid|movie_theatrical_release_date_upd|year|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----+
|12f99f04-5168-438...|98e199d5-37b6-40a...|              2003-04-16 00:00:00|2003|
|32c7d12f-6bf2-4e5...|871e14c1-d046-41a...|              2004-05-28 00:00:00|2004|
|9f067041-3b49-4db...|419d8142-3e1f-489...|              2014-11-26 00:00:00|2014|
|c6d203cb-afcf-4e8...|6a2248de-7024-44c...|              2015-02-06 00:00:00|2015|
|b02416f9-5761-48f...|d7b505c2-5bc6-439...|              2008-06-27 00:00:00|2008|
|4b8a824d-a4f1-4f1...|3843b77d-61ae-427...|              2013-02-14 00:00:00|2013|
|2e522688-8332-4b3...|65e825ec-0486-42f...|              2003-11-14 00:00:00|2003|
|89632328-9a2c-499...|ac307c5e-f55a-40e...|              2012-08-17 00:00:00|2012|
|b670e071-6e9c-437...|e2490660-2fbe-44e...|              1995-12-15 00:00:00|1995|
|064d1587-0b18-434...|b84a04aa-013a-4bf...|              2011-07-22 00:00:00|2011|
|cfac2d11-81b6-408...|f9db54bc-6dc3-471...|              2015-03-13 00:00:00|2015|
```

What I would like to do is create a `decade` column which would like something like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----+------+
|             core_id|                guid|movie_theatrical_release_date_upd|year|decade|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----+------+
|12f99f04-5168-438...|98e199d5-37b6-40a...|              2003-04-16 00:00:00|2003|2000  | 
|32c7d12f-6bf2-4e5...|871e14c1-d046-41a...|              2004-05-28 00:00:00|2004|2000  |
|9f067041-3b49-4db...|419d8142-3e1f-489...|              2014-11-26 00:00:00|2014|2010  |
|c6d203cb-afcf-4e8...|6a2248de-7024-44c...|              2015-02-06 00:00:00|2015|2010  |
|b02416f9-5761-48f...|d7b505c2-5bc6-439...|              2008-06-27 00:00:00|2008|2000  |
```

I am new to pyspark so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show what you've tried already. Also create a [mcve] that doesn't include data not needed for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`floor()`** on decimal of year **`(year/10)`**, and then get desired output by **`multiplying by 10`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("decade", (F.floor(F.col("year")/10)*10).cast("int")).show()

#+----+------+
#|year|decade|
#+----+------+
#|2003|  2000|
#|2004|  2000|
#|2014|  2010|
#|2015|  2010|
#|2008|  2000|
#+----+------+
```

We can also do this by just **`replacing the last number in year with 0`**:

Using **`concat and substring`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("decade", F.expr("""concat(substring(year,1,length(year)-1),0)""")).show()
```

Using **`regexp_replace`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("decade", F.regexp_replace("year",'\d(?!.*\d)','0')).show()
```

Using **`right`** and **`subtract from year`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("decade", F.expr("""int(year-right(year,1))""")).show()
```

Comment: No worries, you might be posted solution when mine is browser is opened, deleting mine

Comment: @AjayKharade thats what i thought,  i was just baffled to see that both of ours were exactly the same to the dot. what are the odds of that lol